# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'concat')

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose-schema

I have a userSchema which will store the details of the tasks in form of arrays and for this I have created a addTask function in userSchema and I am trying to set its tasks field with the array of some values, but I am getting error: "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'concat')". how to resolve it?

userSchema code

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    email:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    password:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    tasks:[ {
        title: {
            type: String,
        },
        description: {
            type: String,
        },
        date: {
            type: Date,
            default: Date.now
        },
        author: {
            type: String,
        },
        isDone: {
            type: Boolean
        },
        isFail: {
            type: Boolean
        }
    }]
})

// creating task
userSchema.methods.addTask = async(title, description, author)=>{
    try {
        this.tasks = this.tasks.concat({title, description, author});
        await this.save();
        return this.tasks;
        
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
    
}

const User = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);
module.exports = User;
```

Here is the code for post method

```js
router.post("/createtask", async(req, res)=>{
    try {
        const {title, description, author} = req.body;
        console.log("creating a new task");
        if(!title){
            return res.json({error: "plz fill title"});
        }
        const userfound = await User.findOne({email: req.body.email});
        console.log(userfound);
        if(userfound){
            const userTask = await userfound.addTask(title, description, author);
            await userfound.save();
            res.status(201).json({message: "successfully created a task."});
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tasks field is optional, so if it was not given a value when the user document was created tasks will be undefined.

This means that when you go to add the first task to a user `this.tasks` is undefined so `this.tasks.concat(...` fails as expected.

To fix this, either define a default of `[]` in the mongoose schema, or in the addTask function, check if tasks is undefined before calling `concat`.